# Why does my Chrome Extension code not open a new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that makes a new tab open to a specific URL upon a new page being loaded. I figured I should start by learning how to create a new tab at all. My code is below.

manifest.json

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "desctiption",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background" : {
    "page" : "background.html",
    "persistent" : false
  }
}

//something.js
function createTab() {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"});
}

<!--background.html-->
<html>
  <head>
    <body>
      <script src="something.js"></script>
      <a href="#" onclick="createTab();">Create a new tab</a>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The inline function `createTab()` is never executed since [JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) and inline statements are not allowed.

Instead, bind to the event within your JS file and move your  tag below the  element.

For example, HTML:

```
<body>
   <a id="myHREF">Create a new tab</a>
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

And your javascript:

```
function createTab() {
   chrome.tabs.create({
       url: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
   });
}

document.getElementById("myHREF").onclick = createTab;
```

Comment: I think OP has mentioned that html and js are already in separate files

Comment: Note the background.html and something.js and inclusion of something.js in background.html shows it. Isn't it ?

Comment: I'm talking about the inline statement "createTab();".  This won't fire.

Comment: Aah..Thanks for explanation..Sorry I misunderstood your point

Comment: @blunderboy No worries, I wasn't very clear originally.  I've updated the post to reflect.

Comment: Something's still not quite right. createTab() still seems to never fire.

Comment: Works for me perfectly.  Make sure the <script> is at the bottom of your HTML body and that you bind to the onclick event from JS.